# reading a file using fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

i have a little problem with my program. 
It should read the first line of file which contains "i" and then print out the "i" column.
i have no idea how to "fix" it

```
char czytaj(const char *fname)
{
FILE *fh = fopen(fname,"r"); 
int i;
char tabelka[100][100];
int k=0;
int w=0;
if(fh == NULL)
{
    printf("cos zjebales\n");
    return 0;
}

fscanf(fh,"%d",&i); 
printf("%d\n", i);
//while(!feof(fh))
//while(k<5)
{
fscanf(fh,"%s",&tabelka[k][w]);
if(tabelka[k][w]=='\n')
{
    w=w+1;
    k=0;
}
else
{   
    k=k+1;
}
}


fclose(fh);
}
```

and here is the file

```
3 \n
Kol01 Kol02 Kol03 Kol04 \n
aa 10 11 31 \n
bb 20 21 32 \n
cc 30 31 33 \n
dd 40 41 43 \n
```

:)

Comment: The expression `&tabelka[k][w]` does not do what you expect it to, especially in the context of `fscanf` with the `"%s"` format. I recommend you step through the program in a debugger, while monitoring all variable values (especially the array).

Comment: What happened to indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int czytaj(const char *fname){
    FILE *fh = fopen(fname, "r"); 
    int col, row;
    int i, ch;
    char tabelka[100][100];

    if(fh == NULL){
        printf("cos zjebales\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fscanf(fh,"%d", &col); 
    printf("%d\n", col);
    --col;//to 0 orign from 1 origin

    for(row = 0;EOF!=(ch = getc(fh));++row){
        ungetc(ch, fh);
        for(i=0;i<col;++i)
            fscanf(fh, " %*s");//skip col-1 column

        fscanf(fh, " %s", tabelka[row]);
        printf("%s\n", tabelka[row]);
        while('\n' != (ch = getc(fh)) && EOF != ch)
            ;
    }
    fclose(fh);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` is not the right routine for the task. It reads tokens of non-whitespace* across lines, i.e it treats the end of the line like any other whitespace.

For your task of separating columns, better read each line with `fgets` and then split the string with `strtok` until you reach the desired column. You don't need space for the whole table, treat the lines one by one, only using one reasonably-sized char buffer for the current line.

*) ignoring the `%[...]` specifier for the moment.